# ArangoDB Date Math - Month difference

Tags: date, arangodb, aql

Utilizing the `DATE_SUBTRACT` function in AQL, when handling dates near the end of the month, Arango seems to subtract 30 days instead of returning the actual previous month. e.g.:

```
for mo in 0..11
    let month = date_subtract(date_now(),count,"month")
    return month
```

returns

```
[
  "2016-08-31T20:30:24.440Z",
  "2016-07-31T20:30:24.441Z",
  "2016-07-01T20:30:24.441Z",
  "2016-05-31T20:30:24.441Z",
  "2016-05-01T20:30:24.441Z",
  "2016-03-31T20:30:24.441Z",
  "2016-03-02T20:30:24.441Z",
  "2016-01-31T20:30:24.441Z",
  "2015-12-31T20:30:24.441Z",
  "2015-12-01T20:30:24.441Z",
  "2015-10-31T20:30:24.441Z",
  "2015-10-01T20:30:24.441Z"
]
```

As you can see, this returns July twice, May twice, March twice, December twice, and October twice.

I actually just need  the prior 12 months. The list I'd like is:

```
[
  "2016-08-01T00:00:00.000Z",
  "2016-07-01T00:00:00.000Z",
  "2016-06-01T00:00:00.000Z", 
  "2016-05-01T00:00:00.000Z", 
  "2016-04-01T00:00:00.000Z", 
  "2016-03-01T00:00:00.000Z",
  "2016-02-01T00:00:00.000Z", 
  "2016-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
  "2015-12-01T00:00:00.000Z",
  "2015-11-01T00:00:00.000Z",
  "2015-10-01T00:00:00.000Z",
  "2015-09-01T00:00:00.000Z"
]
```

How in AQL could I ensure I always get the actual previous month instead of simply 30 days in the past? I fear that the `date_subtract` function won't handle leap years or 31sts.

Answer (score 1):

It's hacky, but I managed to accomplish what I was after with this:

```
for mo in 0..11
    return date_subtract(concat(left(date_iso8601(date_now()),7),'-01T00:00:00.000Z'), mo, "month")
```

Resulting in:

```
[
  "2016-08-01T00:00:00.000Z",
  "2016-07-01T00:00:00.000Z",
  "2016-06-01T00:00:00.000Z",
  "2016-05-01T00:00:00.000Z",
  "2016-04-01T00:00:00.000Z",
  "2016-03-01T00:00:00.000Z",
  "2016-02-01T00:00:00.000Z",
  "2016-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
  "2015-12-01T00:00:00.000Z",
  "2015-11-01T00:00:00.000Z",
  "2015-10-01T00:00:00.000Z",
  "2015-09-01T00:00:00.000Z"
]
```

I would *love* a simpler solution to this, so please let me know if there is one. All those functions are a bunch of overhead.

Comment: JavaScript is used to calculate dates behind the scenes, and if you add a month there, the day changes. Whether this is good or bad depends on the use case IMO. The drawback of only changing the month number (and year on over-/underflow ) would be that multiple days at the end of some months would map to the last day of another month, e.g. 2017-01-28 through 2017-01-31 to 2017-02-28. The other way around, it's even more complicated - should Feb 28th map to Jan/Mar 28th or 31st? Or something in between?

Comment: It is very confusing- for my purposes I definitely want subtraction of a month to report for the prior month, not for the same month or skipping a month. Very rarely do I care about what happened on "today's date, last month" but I do greatly care about aggregating data on a monthly basis. My above solution works, but I really would like to have a reliable in-database function that accomplishes that.